# What html character is this �

Tags: html, internet-explorer, special-characters

This page (http://www.itconsult.net.nz/expertise.html) at the bottom has a character like � (just before and after Engage — Execute — Exit) if you view it using Chrome or FF browser.

Internet Explorer does not show this character. Can somebody please tell me what is the html code for this character or CSS or IE hack to show this character in IE browser?

Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

You have an encoding problem: These are some fancy quote characters encoded in ISO-8859-1, while your page is encoded as UTF-8. Force your browser to display the page in ISO to see what I mean:

```
 “ Engage — Execute — Exit ”
```

Depending on where the content comes from, either change the file's encoding to UTF-8 in an editor, or the database connection's encoding if it comes from a database.

Good basic reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is geomatic shapes,

Please find the respected geomaric shape code and remove it from your code

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo/fonts.fo